# Getting back sums of specific entries

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, union, aggregate-functions

I posted [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277874/trying-to-get-the-sum-of-distinct-values-for-distinct-files-for-distinct-softwar) about an issue and I thought it had been resolved only to my great anguish to find that it wasn't doing what I thought it was.

So I'm just going to post the entire query for posterity because neither me or my supervisor can figure it out.

```
--declare variables    
declare @dbname nvarchar (200); --database name from scenario regression reports
declare @query nvarchar (max); --query to retrieve regression data 
declare @testid int;

--declare the cursor by selecting database names with the abcdbname tag. All test scenarios must include this tag in the report base name
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
select name from sys.databases
where name like '%abcdbname%' 

--query to set the testid equal to previous test id + 1
select  @testid = coalesce(MAX(TestNum), 0) from [TestLog].RegressionTable
set @testid = @testid + 1;

Open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @dbname

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 --keep going as long as there is more in the list of db names

BEGIN

  --define a query that counts people by final disposition, scenario run time, and report database size.
  set @query = CAST('select (select attributedata from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where AttributeName = 'Scenario Name') as Scenario_Name, 
        (select attributedata from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where AttributeName = 'Version') as Version, 
        CAST(count(*) as float)/MAX(repnum) as value, finalDisposition as Measure, GETDATE() as DateRun, (select ' + CAST(@testid as CHAR) +') as TestNum from [' +@dbname+ '].table2 
        group by FinalDisposition  

        union

        select (select attributedata from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where AttributeName = ''Scenario Name'') as Scenario_Name, 
       (select attributedata from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where AttributeName = 'Version') as Version,
        CAST(LEFT((select attributedata from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where AttributeName = 'Scenario Execution Elapsed Time'), 
        CHARINDEX('m',(select attributedata from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where AttributeName = 'Scenario Execution Elapsed Time'),1 )-2) as float) as  Value, 
       (select 'Run Time') as Measure, GETDATE() as DateRun, (select ' + CAST(@testid as CHAR) +') as TestNum  from [' +@dbname+ '].table2
        group by FinalDisposition

        union

        select (select attributedata from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where AttributeName = 'Scenario Name') as Scenario_Name, 
       (select attributedata from [' +@dbname+ '].table1 where AttributeName = 'Version') as Version,
       (SELECT cast((size*8)/1024 as float) SizeMB FROM sys.master_files
         where DB_NAME(database_id) = ''' +@dbname+ ''' and type = 0) as  value, 
       (select ''DBSize'') as Measure, GETDATE() as DateRun, (select ' + CAST(@testid as CHAR) +') as TestNum  from [' +@dbname+ '].table2
        group by FinalDisposition  ' as nvarchar (max))

-- This is the part that I added specifically. 
-- It isn't yeilding an error message but its not doing the math that it is supposed to do. 
-- I'll explain further below.

        union 

        select (select attributedata from table2 where AttributeName = 'Scenario Name') as Scenario_Name, 
        (select attributedata from table1 where AttributeName = 'Version') as Version, 
        (select CAST(COUNT(*) as float)/MAX(repnum) from table2 where FinalDisposition = 'Weekends' or FinalDisposition = 'Weekdays') as Value, 
        'Total People' as Measure,
        GETDATE() as DateRun, (select 100) as TestNum;                 

  --the two lines below insert the results of the query above into the test log database. those results are then read from an R script for generating a test report
  Insert INTO [TestLog].RegressionTable(Scenario_Name,Version, Value, Measure, DateRun, TestNum)
  Execute (@query)
  --iterate through the list of test scenarios
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname 

END
Close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

Okay so the very last select under the last union is what I'm trying to get to work. It is supposed to return the sum of two results that are pulled from other databases. I'm just going to post a link to the original question because I'm exhausted after trying to figure this out all day and it'll be easier probably just to read through what the original issue was.

[Trying to get the sum of distinct values for distinct files for distinct software versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277874/trying-to-get-the-sum-of-distinct-values-for-distinct-files-for-distinct-softwar)

EDIT: I have officially figured it out! I know I'm one of the few excited about that lol but as usual it was a simple mistake and brain fart on my end.

```
select 
    (select attributedata from table2 where AttributeName = 'Scenario Name') as Scenario_Name, 
    (select attributedata from table1 where AttributeName = 'Version') as Version, 
    ISNULL(CAST(COUNT(*) as float)/MAX(repnum),0) as Value, 
    'Total People' as Measure,
    GETDATE() as DateRun,
    (select ' + CAST(@testid as CHAR) +') as TestNum
FROM table2 
WHERE FinalDisposition = 'Weekends' or FinalDisposition = 'Weekdays'
```

Comment: Oh what is this ;-) How should the select under the last select doing a sum without having a sum there? The selects in the select part are returning just one value and row each? Is the datatype of the column repnum also float? Did you test this Statement alone?

Comment: Yes, the statement should work without a sum because its counting the number of entries period from the other database and it should only count the ones that have the Measure entry of "Weekends" or "weekdays" and I left the group by statement out so that it would put them all together. When I put use just the `select CAST(COUNT(*) AS float)/MAS(repnum) as Value, 'Total People' as Measure,  where FinalDisposition = 'Weekends' OR FinalDisposition = 'Weekdays' from table2` This works perfectly. Its when I incorporate the rest of the query that things break.

Comment: It seems to return more than just Weekend and Weekdays and it also has counted the total entries for all the entries its pulling and that total number is being dumped into either each Entry for Measure which have all been renamed to 'Total People' or if I leave group by out, then it just gives the one entry back but its counting more than just the Weekends and Weekdays. I'm guessing that the where isn't in the right spot or isn't the right way to go about this.